# UITableViewCell don't show up data until scroll down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

My `JSON` response to `UITableView`.

But, `UITableView` isn't show up data until scroll down.

Please help me.How to resolve it?

Sorry for my bad English language. Because, I can speak English a little bit.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    globlOnDisplayEffect = [GlobalVariable sharedInstance];
    globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelectedWhereHouse = [[NSArray alloc] init];

}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]>0 ?[globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]:1;

}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell";
    DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    } 
    if (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected) {
        NSMutableArray *myMutbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [myMutbleArray addObject:globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected];
        if (myMutbleArray)
        {
                NSDictionary *myDic = [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10"];
                NSString *f10_cmpt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_cmpt"]];
                NSString *f10_dt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_dt"]];
                NSString *f10_item = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_item"]];
                NSString *f10_lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_lot"]];
                NSString *f10_model = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_model"]];
                NSString *f10_of = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_of"]];
                NSString *f10_semi = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_semi"]];
                NSString *f10_tm = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_tm"]];
                NSString *f10_uncmp = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_uncmp"]];
               [cell setf10_cmpt:f10_cmpt setf10_dt:f10_dt setf10_item:f10_item setf10_lot:f10_lot setf10_model:f10_model setf10_of:f10_of setf10_semi:f10_semi setf10_tm:f10_tm setf10_uncmp:f10_uncmp];
         }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: have you `reload` your tableview while assign your JSON to `UITableView`?

Comment: just remove the else condition .

Comment: Cell data are not showing for else. Remove else.

Comment: I'm remove else follow you.
But, when scroll down is error such as below.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (10) beyond bounds (10)'

Comment: Can u share the content of globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected. So that i can help u how to parse the data

Answer (score 0):

Do this --

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell";
    DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }  if (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected) {
        NSMutableArray *myMutbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [myMutbleArray addObject:globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected];
         if (myMutbleArray)
        {
            NSDictionary *myDic = [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10"];
            NSString *f10_cmpt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_cmpt"]];
            NSString *f10_dt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_dt"]];
            NSString *f10_item = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_item"]];
            NSString *f10_lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_lot"]];
            NSString *f10_model = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_model"]];
            NSString *f10_of = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_of"]];
            NSString *f10_semi = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_semi"]];
            NSString *f10_tm = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_tm"]];
            NSString *f10_uncmp = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_uncmp"]];

            [cell setf10_cmpt:f10_cmpt setf10_dt:f10_dt setf10_item:f10_item setf10_lot:f10_lot setf10_model:f10_model setf10_of:f10_of setf10_semi:f10_semi setf10_tm:f10_tm setf10_uncmp:f10_uncmp];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Just remove the else brackets.
The thing you were doing is if cell is not found after dequeue you are returning an empty cell, and in the next time when scrolling, it is going inside the else block and it is being filled up with data. 
So, just remove the else brackets.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (10) beyond bounds (10)'

Comment: When scroll down.

Comment: Your problem about not showing cell was due to the else part. The crash is because the array from where you are populating, is finding wrong index as to the index doesnt exists in the array and you are trying to access that. This part you have to solve on your own, as this is a logical error that you would know what to do. 
Cheers.

Comment: I'm a new developer. I'm try to resolve this problem 4-6 day.
But, I'm really not found the method to resolve it.
Please somebody help me.

Comment: Now, i can resolved logical error and follow your code. But It isn't work.
UITableView isn't show up data.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code with the existing one.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell";
    DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    } 
    //check whether the globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected is empty
    if(globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected  != nil && [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count] > 0){
                NSDictionary *myDic = [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10"];
                NSString *f10_cmpt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_cmpt"]];
                NSString *f10_dt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_dt"]];
                NSString *f10_item = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_item"]];
                NSString *f10_lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_lot"]];
                NSString *f10_model = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_model"]];
                NSString *f10_of = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_of"]];
                NSString *f10_semi = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_semi"]];
                NSString *f10_tm = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_tm"]];
                NSString *f10_uncmp = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_uncmp"]];
               [cell setf10_cmpt:f10_cmpt setf10_dt:f10_dt setf10_item:f10_item setf10_lot:f10_lot setf10_model:f10_model setf10_of:f10_of setf10_semi:f10_semi setf10_tm:f10_tm setf10_uncmp:f10_uncmp];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Also you have to reload the tableview with the following line. Whenever you Added a content inside the `globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected`

```
[self.tableViewDetailList reloadData];
```